# Tkinter, alignment - the endless question

Tags: python, tkinter, alignment

Since some days I'll try to align these two items inside a Tkinter frame:

[image]

The pink part should be on the left and the green button on the right. With HtmlDivs and CSS a question of seconds, with TKinter a pain in the ...

*Here is my python code:*

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")


buttons = tk.Frame(root)
buttons.pack(side="top", expand=True, fill='both')

label = tk.Label(buttons, text="Hello, world", anchor='w', background='pink')
b2 = tk.Button(buttons, text="EXIT", background='green')


label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w', ipadx = '20', padx = '20')
b2.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='e', ipadx = '20', padx = '20')


root.mainloop()
```

The final app will be running fullscreen on a 7" touch display.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a grid layout since you just have two items, one on the left and one on the right?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `pack` instead of grid, since you only have a single row of widgets inside of `buttons`. `pack`'s strength is arranging things in a single row or a single column.

Just remove these two lines:

```
label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='w', ipadx = '20', padx = '20')
b2.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky='e', ipadx = '20', padx = '20')
```

... and replace them with this:

```
label.pack(side='left')
b2.pack(side='right')
```

Also, since you appear to be creating a toolbar, you want to leave `expand` as `False` and set `fill` to just "x", otherwise the toolbar will expand to fill the entire window:

```
buttons.pack(side="top", expand=False, fill='x')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your tips,

this is just a testcode to update my maincode.
Its not good to mix .pack and .grid, right ? If i do, the script crashes completely, 
so ill have to re-do my mainscript i think.

This is what i need:

1. row: 1/2: label (it will be a real time clock) left 2/2: exit button (exit fullscreen) right
2. row: 1/3: image (weather), 2/3: weather data (label), 3/3: calendar
3. row: 4 buttons: 1. lightoff 2. light25%, 3.light50% 4.light100&

Thats it basically all is working, it just need to align it (im a coding hero *g*)

Since i have the frame from the code above, i thought i can easily add 2. & 3. row with another frames, but that does not seem to work ??

Preview:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzoqV.png

My (main)Code so far

```
root = Tk()
root.title('Model Definition')
root.config(background = "deepskyblue4")
root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
root.bind('<Escape>',lambda e: root.destroy())

def currenttime(): 
    string = strftime("%A, %d.%B.%Y %H:%M:%S") 
    lbl.config(text = string, background = 'deepskyblue4', fg='white', font=("colibri", 30)) 
    lbl.after(1000, currenttime)


def light400():
    FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    subprocess.call(['gpio -g pwm 18 401'], stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)

def light425():
    FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    subprocess.call(['gpio -g pwm 18 425'], stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)

def light450():
    FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    subprocess.call(['gpio -g pwm 18 450'], stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)

def light475():
    FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    subprocess.call(['gpio -g pwm 18 500'], stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)




# Main frames
top_frame = Frame(root, bg='deepskyblue4', width=450, height=90, pady=3)
center = Frame(root, bg='deepskyblue2', width=50, height=40, padx=3, pady=3)
btm_frame = Frame(root, bg='deepskyblue4', width=450, height=20, pady=3)
btm_frame2 = Frame(root, bg='deepskyblue4', width=450, height=60, pady=3)

# layout all of the main containers
root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
top_frame.grid(row=0, sticky="e", padx=(10, 0))
center.grid(row=1, sticky="nsew", pady=(10, 50))
btm_frame.grid(row=3, sticky="ew")
btm_frame2.grid(row=4, sticky="ew", padx=(10, 50))

# create the widgets for the top frame

lbl = Label(top_frame, background = 'deepskyblue4', anchor=W, justify=LEFT)
lbl.pack()
currenttime()
actionbutton = Button(top_frame, text="X", width=5, height=2, bg="deepskyblue4", fg="white", command=root.destroy)


hdr_left = Frame(top_frame, bg='deepskyblue4', width=100, height=190)
hdr_right = Frame(top_frame, bg='deepskyblue4', width=400, height=190, padx=3, pady=3)

# layout the widgets in the top frame
lbl.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w")
actionbutton.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="e")

# create the center widgets
center.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
center.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

ctr_left = Frame(center, bg='deepskyblue2', width=100, height=190)
ctr_mid = Frame(center, bg='deepskyblue2', width=150, height=190, padx=3, pady=3)
ctr_right = Frame(center, bg='deepskyblue2', width=400, height=190, padx=3, pady=3)

ctr_left.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")
ctr_mid.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
ctr_right.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="ns")

path = "icons/rain.png"
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = Label(ctr_left, image = img, bg="deepskyblue2")
panel.grid(row=0, columnspan=3)
#imgag = panel.pack(top_frame)

#CENTER ctr_mid
if x["cod"] != "404": 

    y = x["main"]
    y2 = x["wind"]
    currenttemp = y["temp"] 
    currentpressure = y["pressure"] 
    currenthumidiy = y["humidity"]
    z = x["weather"]
    weather_description = z[0]["description"]
    currentwind = y2["speed"]

    label1 = Label(ctr_mid,text='Karlsruhe', font = ('calibri', 30), background = 'deepskyblue2')
    label2 = Label(ctr_mid,text='Temperatur: '+str(round(currenttemp-272.15))+' °C', font = ('calibri', 20), background = 'deepskyblue2')
    label3 = Label(ctr_mid,text='Beschreibung: '+str(weather_description),font = ('calibri', 20), background = 'deepskyblue2')
    label4 = Label(ctr_mid,text='Druck: '+str(currentpressure)+' hPa', font = ('calibri', 20), background = 'deepskyblue2')
    label5 = Label(ctr_mid,text='Feuchtigkeit: '+str(currenthumidiy)+' %',font = ('calibri', 20), background = 'deepskyblue2')
    label6 = Label(ctr_mid,text='Wind: '+str(currentwind)+' m/Sek',font = ('calibri', 20), background = 'deepskyblue2')

    label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")
    label2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nw")
    label3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nw")
    label4.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="nw")
    label5.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="nw")
    label6.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="nw")

# btm_frame2 widgets
licht = Label(btm_frame2, text='Licht:', width=5, height=1, bg="deepskyblue4", fg='white', font=("colibri", 20))
button = Button(btm_frame2, command=light400, text="AUS", width=5, height=1, bg="deepskyblue2", fg="white")
button2 = Button(btm_frame2, text="25 %", command=light425, width=5, height=1, bg="deepskyblue2", fg="white")
button3 = Button(btm_frame2, text="50%", command=light450, width=5, height=1, bg="deepskyblue2", fg="white")
button4 = Button(btm_frame2, text="100%", command=light475, width=5, height=1, bg="deepskyblue2", fg="white")



licht.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nw")
button.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nw")
button2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nw")
button3.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="nw")
button4.grid(row=0, column=4, sticky="nw")
actionbutton.grid(row=0, column=6, sticky="nw")


root.mainloop()
```